# After installing Anaconda, Scikit-learn.datasets isn't working

Tags: python, syntax, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am having an issue using Anaconda and Scikit-learn.  When I do the tutorial on their site : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html it comes back with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Max/.PyCharmCE2017.1/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 1, in <module>
from sklearn import datasets
File "D:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
from .mldata import fetch_mldata, mldata_filename
File "D:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\mldata.py", line 12, in <module>
from urllib2 import HTTPError
File "D:\Python\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 254
raise AttributeError, attr
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anaconda is updated and sklearn is as well.  I'm not sure where the issue is on this.  I think it has something to do with urllib2 not being in python 3 but from what I've read it sklearn is comparable.

Comment: It seems like you mixed up your python 2 and python 3 installations. Try removing `urllib2.py`.

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks a lot.  Don't know what happened there.